# How can I get the current system time in milliseconds or nanosec?

Tags: ocaml

`Unix.time()` returns seconds.

How can I get the time in ms or ns?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `Unix.gettimeofday`

```
# Unix.time ();;
- : float = 1447865942.
# Unix.gettimeofday();;
- : float = 1447865947.56802297
```

Answer (score 3):

Core has very robust time related functions, and since 112.06.00 there is a `Time_ns` module.

```
utop # Time_ns.now();;
- : Time_ns.t = 2015-11-18 14:49:08.580109-05:00
```