# Getting current second with millisecond precision in OCaml

Tags: time, ocaml

I'd like to get the current second in the minute with millisecond precision. Valid values could be: `23.432`, `51.027`, etc. with the integer part in the range of 1-60 (seconds in the minute), and the decimal part being the milliseconds (0-999).

I've found that the standard library can give me the seconds by doing the following:

```
let t = Unix.localtime (Unix.time ())
Printf.printf "Current seconds value %02d\n" t.tm_sec
```

But with that method I don't get milliseconds. I can get millisecond precision (and more) using `Unix.gettimeofday ()`, but then I have to figure out how to add the decimal part of that value to the current seconds, which seems cumbersome for such simple operation. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the current system time in milliseconds or nanosec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785791/how-can-i-get-the-current-system-time-in-milliseconds-or-nanosec)

Comment: See http://micdel.fr/oclock.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Unix.gettimeofday ()` if you establish a base time when the seconds in the minute were 0 and such that all subsequent minutes have been 60 seconds long. The last leap second was in 2016. So you can ask for the time at (say) the beginning of Jan 1, 2017 and use that as your base.

I tried the following and it seemed to work for me:

```
let (base, _) = Unix.mktime {
    tm_sec = 0;
    tm_min = 0;
    tm_hour = 0;
    tm_mday = 1;
    tm_mon = 0;
    tm_year = 117;
    tm_wday = 0;
    tm_yday = 0;
    tm_isdst = false;
}

let seconds_in_minute () =
    mod_float (Unix.gettimeofday () -. base) 60.0
```

In other words, a quick test showed that the value flipped back to 0.0 when the time displayed on my computer went over to the next minute.

This should work until the next leap second is added by the time lords. Maybe that will be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Maybe get gettimeofday, localtime and gettimeofday (again) at start and compute the base from there. The second  gettimeofday is to detect the race condition when the times you got where at x.999 and (x+1).001, the second changed while you got the times. Make sure both gettimeofday have the same second part. If not try again.