# Is there is a function that can tell me the time in seconde?

Tags: ocaml

I work with Ocaml and in my project I need to calculate a score who depend of the time.
In order to do this, I try this way :

The score have an int ref and his value is 0 at the begining.
Every 10s we increase this value by 1.(I use a recursive fuction to repeat this line)

```ml
let t : int ref = ref 0;;

let rec score(t : int ref) : int ref =
    (*-------time function where I need help-------*) 
    t := !t + 1;
    score;
    ;;
```

Comment: Please, search the internet before posing a question that already has been answered on StackOverflow before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785791/how-can-i-get-the-current-system-time-in-milliseconds-or-nanosec

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to decide which time you need. `Sys.time` will give you the CPU time and `Unix.gettimeofday` will give you the wall-clock time. I usually prefer the latter.

Next, it is easier just to remember the start time and then count the number of seconds since the start and divide it by 10:

```
let tens_of_seconds_since_the_program_start =
  let start = Unix.gettimeofday () in
  fun () ->
    let now = Unix.gettimeofday () in
    int_of_float @@ Float.round ((now -. start) /. 10.)
```

As the name of the function tells, it will return the one-tenth of the number of seconds that have passed since the program has started. It will use the wall-clock time.

An alternative solution would be using `Unix.alarm` or interval times (`Unix.getitemer`, `Unix.setiterm`) to update the counter asynchronously every ten seconds, e.g.,

```
let score = ref 0

let start_timer () =
  let update _ =
    incr score;
    ignore (Unix.alarm 10) in
  ignore (Sys.signal Sys.sigalrm (Signal_handle update));
  Unix.alarm 10;
```

This code will update the `score` reference asynchronously, but asynchronous execution has a lot of caveats so I highly advise against this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The [time](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Sys.html#VALtime) function of the `Sys` module does this. You can call it twice and use the difference to see how much time has passed during the two calls.